# Add valve to water filter supply line

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I have a PureBlue H20 Reverse osmosis water filter system and want to add a water valve for it. Not sure which type of valve and size I should get and whether to put the valve on the main valve itself or on the plastic connections.

I would like some recommendations on the best and cheap option.

[image: water valve connections]

Comment: [Cut the line, slip the ends into this (or similar--for type reference only), done.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Quick-Connect-1-4-in-Plastic-Straight-Valve-PL-3011/100112645)

Comment: I want to be able to control the water flow from the plastic T fitting tube that goes to the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that water line to the filter is 1/4 tubing.   Go to local big box hardware store. int he plumbing section there will be a selection on little bags containing either brass or plastic parts, valves, compression fittings etc.

Find either a compression fittingGood) or a push-in valve(Better) for the tubing size.  Either way make sure cuts to tubing a clean and square, no angles use a knife and piece of scrap wood to cut...not a pair of scissors.

Which ever you chose follow instructions to install correctly!